# Cannot Edit in Django

Tags: python, django

I have the following views:

```
def unit_edit(request,pk):
    post = Unit.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        vehicle_group   = request.POST.get('vehicle_group'),
        unit_name       = request.POST.get('unit_name'),
        start_hm        = request.POST.get('start_hm'),
        operation_date  = request.POST.get('operation_date'),
        coremoduleid    = request.POST.get('coremoduleid'),
        mqmoduleid      = request.POST.get('mqmoduleid'),
        radiomoduleid   = request.POST.get('radiomoduleid'),
        post.save()

    t = loader.get_template('unit_edit.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {'unit': post})

    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

The problem:

When I try to edit a given object (data), I cannot get the data to be edited.

Comment: You do not validate the data in any way. User can insert ANY data into the database by altering the POST params. Consider using [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) instead of manual assiging of values from `request.POST`.

Comment: Do not update the question with the answer. It makes it look like answers are incorrect or not adding anything. Please create a new question if this is the case.

Comment: i am sorry, i edit the question same time with the answer. So, i don't know if someone already answer my question and the answer is not correct, i still have error..

Comment: I think the best thing for you to do is read the django tutorial (from the beginning) paying special attention to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial04/

Comment: Please create a new question regarding your new issue.

Comment: i should be done create new question but You can only post once every 90 minutes

Comment: There's no point just saying "I am not using a form". You *should* be using a form.

Comment: Please don't continually fix code based on answers. If you fixing the issue at hand results in *new* problems, you'll need to ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually editing the object you get from the database. Your code is currently setting a number of variables not object attributes. You need to prefix the variables with the `post` object.

By doing `post.variable_name = <value>` you are modifying the objects attribute value.

By doing `variable_name = <value>` you are creating and setting a value to a function variable.

```
def unit_edit(request,pk):
    post = Unit.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        post.vehicle_group   = request.POST.get('vehicle_group'),
        post.unit_name       = request.POST.get('unit_name'),
        post.start_hm        = request.POST.get('start_hm'),
        post.operation_date  = request.POST.get('operation_date'),
        post.coremoduleid    = request.POST.get('coremoduleid'),
        post.mqmoduleid      = request.POST.get('mqmoduleid'),
        post.radiomoduleid   = request.POST.get('radiomoduleid'),
        post.save()
```

Comment: thanks, i already edit my code like that but error like this expected string or buffer. how?